# combine year, month, day, hour, minute and second fields to a one column at "TIMESTAMP" in SQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table which contain following columns, separately:
year, month, day, hour, minute, second

How can I combine them as a single columns in "TIMESTAMP" format?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Taking the other answers together, use them to create a new column for a timestamp and update that to have the real timestamp, then drop the original columns
.  Then you can extract() the pieces you want later easily and you'll have an actual timestamp the rest of the time.  This is one of those times the original designer got too smart so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT year || '-' || month  || '-' || day  || ' ' || hour  || ':' || minute  || ':' || second FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use concatenation and cast to timestamp.
Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (year integer, month integer, day integer,
                   hour integer, min integer,   sec integer);

INSERT INTO  test (year, month, day, hour, min, sec)
           VALUES (2012,    10,  11,   01,  10,  35);

SELECT (year::text || '-' || month::text || '-' || day::text || ' '
     || hour::text || ':' || min::text   || ':' || sec::text)::timestamp
FROM test

"timestamp"
"10/11/2012 1:10:35 AM"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Postgres 9.4 this became [a lot easier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
select make_timestamp(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) as ts_value
from the_table;
```

This assumes that all columns are integer (except for `second` which could also be a double)

And to create a `date`, use `make_date()`, for a `time` value use `make_time()`